# Console says cannot find a variable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I declared a variable circles but somehow it's not being accessed here (near the bottom of the file)

```
circles.filter(function(d, i){
               return d.species == species
                })
```

My console says it can't find variable: circles. I'm a total novice to d3.js & javascript so any help is much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/flyingburrito/gacbucyo/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're defining `circles` inside your `d3.csv(...)` call, but then referencing it in a separate `d3.selectAll(...)` call. Thus `circles` is not defined for the `d3.selectAll(...)` as it is out of scope. Try making `circles` a global variable by defining it at the top of your JSFiddle. Then, initialize it without using `var`:

```
circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
```

After I made this fix I no longer had an error and could filter circles. See [updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/mny4qL1j/).

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that!

Comment: @JamesWang: glad to help! Just a friendly reminder: if you feel my answer solved your problem, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Circles is not a global variable and therefore you can't see it at the end of the file. Define it at the top like you have the others (svg, data, ..) and then you'll be able to access it.